# craco don't work with react-scripts@^5.0.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-scripts, craco

it shows me this error:

yarn start                                                          ✔  27s 
yarn run v1.22.19
$ craco start
Failed to compile.

For the selected environment is no default script chunk format available:
JSONP Array push can be chosen when 'document' or 'importScripts' is available.
CommonJs exports can be chosen when 'require' or node builtins are available.
Make sure that your 'browserslist' includes only platforms that support these features or select an appropriate 'target' to allow selecting a chunk format by default. Alternatively, specify the 'output.chunkFormat' directly.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

And this is my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "fly-with-zoki",
  "version": "1.10.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider": "^0.3.2",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.16",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.114",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.17",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.10.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.8.0-0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.29.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "amadeus": "^7.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dom-lib": "^3.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "history": "5.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "json-schema-to-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "lib": "^4.3.3",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "node": "^16.13.0",
    "notistack": "^1.0.10",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartist": "0.14.4",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.8",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.3.2",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS= next dev",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "build-package-css": "cp src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css dist/material-dashboard-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.9",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": []
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

I have tried to upgrade my react-scripts by using

```
npm ugdate react-scripts 
npm upgrade react-scripts 
yarn update react-scripts  
yarn upgrade react-scripts
```

But no changes were applied :(